# How can you check if a user clicked the right answer to a quiz program?

Tags: javascript

The following code segments are of ajax, javascript, html and an xml file.

I need to total up the score from the users input to see if they clicked the right answers for the test. I tried to solve this but I'm not sure how you create the necessary code to solve this problem.

I would greatly appreciate some advice and thank you for reading this.

```
This is the javascript and ajax file.

var score;
var i;

function loaddata() {

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
 // r = xhr.JSONparse(responseText);
  displayData(xhr);
 }
};
xhr.open("GET", "FinalQuiz.xml", true);
xhr.send();
}

function displayData(xhr) {
console.log(xhr);

//get data as xml file
var xmldoc = xhr.responseXML;
//start table
var output="";
//process data by record
var x = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("question");

for(i = 0; i<x.length; i++)
{
output+="Question ";
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("qnumber")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
output+="<br>";
output+="Title: ";
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("qtitle")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
output+="<br>";
output+= "<button onclick=\"answer()\">A</button>" ;
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
output+="<br>";
output+= "<button onclick=\"answer()\">B</button>" ;
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("b")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
output+="<br>";
output+= "<button onclick=\"answer()\">C</button>" ;
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("c")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
output+="<br>";
output+= "<button onclick=\"answer()\">D</button>" ;
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("d")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
output+="<br>";
output+="<br>";
}
document.getElementById("quiz").innerHTML = output;
}

function answer()
{
score = score + 1;
}
```

This is the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE finalquiz SYSTEM "FinalQuiz.dtd" >
<finalquiz>
<question>
<qnumber>1</qnumber>
<qtitle>In a switch statement, the ________ case clause is used to process exceptional conditions and is usually listed last.</qtitle>
<a>break</a>
<b>default</b>
<c>else</c>
<d>then</d>
</question>
<question>
<qnumber>2</qnumber>
<qtitle>The technique of developing and maintaining a large program by     constructing it from small, simple pieces is called ________.</qtitle>
<a>divide and conquer</a>
<b>modular programming</b>
<c>multitasking</c>
<d>multiprogramming</d>
</question>
<question>
<qnumber>3</qnumber>
<qtitle>All variables declared in function definitions are ________.     </qtitle>
<a>global variables</a>
<b>static variables</b>
<c>constant variables</c>
<d>local variables</d>
</question>
<question>
<qnumber>4</qnumber>
<qtitle>A function’s ________ are also considered to be local variables.   </qtitle>
<a>parameters</a>
<b>static variables</b>
<c>register variables</c>
<d>constant variables</d>
</question>
<question>
<qnumber>5</qnumber>
<qtitle>The style of programming in which the user interacts with a GUI component is called ________ programming. </qtitle>
<a>modular</a>
<b>automatic</b>
<c>event driven</c>
<d>object oriented</d>
</question>
<rightanswers>b,a,d,a,c</rightanswers>
</finalquiz>
```

This is the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Quiz</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Bluefish 2.2.7" >
<meta name="author" content="kgoertzen" >
<meta name="date" content="2016-03-21T12:31:24-0700" >
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!-- Bootstrap - Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384- BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"  crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--  Bootstrap - Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!--  Bootstrap - Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script   src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"  integrity="sha384- Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xml.js">
    </script>
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row header">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div>
                    <h1>Kyle Goertzen : 000729347</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li class="active"><a rel="noopener" href="../index.html" href="#">View</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <body onload="loaddata()">
  <div id="quiz"></div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: where are the `answer` key to correct?

Comment: @NishanthMatha it is at the very end of the xml file.

Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are too many things wrong with your program/logic.

Firstly, I assume this is a learning exercise fr you because you can't have answers in the same xml file, that's being rendered on client side (people can easily see the answers with developer tools)

Secondly, your algorithm is pale . There is no logic in your code.

While trying to calculate score there are 2 primariy things:

> 1) what answer was answered for a particular question
>
> 2) what happens if the user changes those answers

For these kind of things you need to choose a appropriate data type to store your answers. I'd recommend to use js `object`

In this object `keys` are question numbers and `values` are individual scores. `Initially, all the individual scores are set to zero if the answer is correct we set to 1 or to 0 if its wrong`

```
var score=0;
var result; // this will have the rightanswers from the xml
var answered ={0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0}; // keys are question numbers , values are individual scores
```

Then your `answer()` doesn't keep record of which question is being answered and what is answers. So we modify it to `answer(i,'a')`,`answer(i,'b')...` where `i` is question number index (starting with 0) and second param is option being clicked.

finally, your logic in `answer` function would look like:

```
function answer(i,ans)
{
  var ansArray = result[0].innerHTML.split(",");
  answered[i]= ansArray[i] == ans ? 1 :0;console.log(answered);
  score = answered[0]+answered[1]+answered[2]+answered[3]+answered[4];
  //alert(score);
}
```

[Working demo 1](https://plnkr.co/edit/q4QFBmInr8iSEnTAWmj0?p=preview)

[Working demo 2](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q1dQqbRQrxjInhijXqwi?p=preview)

P.S: This is just one of the many ways of doing what asked in OP.